# Hexagonate complex shape

Tags: mesh, wireframe

I'm trying to "hexagonate" a complex mesh. The task is to create a hexagonal "shield" around gums. I've tried to create a hexagonal grid and Shrinkwrap it onto the gums but it didn't work.

So, I duplicated the mesh and generated Dual Mesh using Tissue Addon, then used the Wireframe modifier. You can see the effect in the image below. However, what I'm looking for is hexagons of more equal size and the Tissue Addon doesn't give a control over that.

[image]